# Finding the critical points of a trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

So I need the critical points (and note the intervals where the function increases and decreases) for:

$2cos\left(3x\right)$ on the interval $\left[-\pi ,\pi \right]$.

I'll be honest, by far the most difficult part of Calc I for me so far is ANYTHING involving trigonometry. I feel like precalc was aeons ago and I honestly wonder if I ever learned it properly. Taking the derivative of f(x) gets me:

$-6sin\left(3x\right)$, which I have to set to $0$.

I know trig functions and the unit circle, but I feel like anything involving trigonometry behaves in a totally alien way from anything else in mathematics. Even the notation confounds me. How do I find:

$-6sin\left(3x\right) = 0$? And once I have the critical points, how do I take into account $\left[-\pi ,\pi \right]$ in noting where this function increases and decreases?

Comment: If you{re going to have some few courses in mathematics, you better try to enhance your comprehension of trigonometry as it is one of the most important and ubiquous of all subjects in practically all the branches of sciences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying $\sin(3x)=0$ means $3x=k\pi$, for some integer $k$. Therefore $x=k\pi/3$ and you just have to determine all integers $k$ such that $k\pi/3\in[-\pi,\pi]$. Now
$$
-\pi\le \frac{k\pi}{3}\le \pi
$$
is equivalent to
$$
-3\le k\le 3
$$
so we have seven critical points. For telling apart the points of maximum and minimum, the simplest way is to look at the second derivative:
$$
f''(x)=-18\cos(3x)
$$

Note that there are really no problems in the points $-\pi$ and $\pi$ being at the boundaries, because the function you have is the restriction of the function $x\mapsto 2\cos(3x)$ defined over the reals, which is clearly smooth everywhere.

Here's a graph of the function:

[image]

Note that it is the cosine function, but stretched in the vertical direction by the factor $2$ and “compressed” in the horizontal direction by the factor $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember:

$$\sin x=0\iff x=k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z=\{...-2,-1,0,1,2,...\}\;$$ and in your case

$$\sin3x=0\iff 3x=k\pi\in(-\pi,\,\pi)\iff k=0\implies x=0$$

Now, you also have two extreme points $\;\pm\pi\;$, which cannot be checked by the above method as the fucntion isn't differentiable there (as we need a complete neighborhood of a point where the function's defined to even have a chance to take the limit defining the derivative. You check them separately and check these are local extremes.

Comment: The third $\iff$ in your answer is clearly wrong.